# Please explain grammatical composition

Tags: grammar, verbs

> Kindly pay the pending salary of **mentioned** ex-employees

I am writing the above sentence to the finance department but I am not able to understand this sentence grammatical composition, specially why we used **"mentioned"** (the 2nd word).

Comment: **pay** is the main verb of the sentence, an imperative.  **mentioned**, which is formed from the past participle of the verb **mention**,  is used adjectivally there, and has no bearing upon the voice of the sentence.

Comment: Kindly pay the outstanding salary of the employees above.

Answer (score 1):

"mentioned" is a participle, it is functioning like an adjective to describe the employees.  Particples used like this can often be rephrased as relative clauses

> ... the employees that were mentioned.

> ... the employees that I have mentioned.

(Here you can see how the participle developed into the passive voice and the perfect tenses)

The main verb is "pay" which is in the imperative mood (and active voice)

The style is rather old fashioned. And is missing an article "*the* mentioned employees".  It could be reworded in a more businesslike manner

> Please pay the salary of these employees.

Answer (score 0):

> Kindly pay the pending salary of mentioned ex-employees

The use of "mentioned" strikes me as very old-fashioned, and likely to be thought odd by a native speaker of AmE and I think BrE. (I am not as sure about Indian English). It lacks a clearly required article ("the") and an essential qualifier such as "previously".  I would newer write this sentence. In US usage at least, this use of "kindly" is now unusual at best, and should in my view be avoided. I would advise modifying it to a more normal form, such as one of the sentences below (not the "below sentences").

> - Please pay the pending salary of the above-mentioned ex-employees.
> - Please pay the pending salary of the ex-employees mentioned  above.
> - Please pay the pending salary of the ex-employees that I have mentioned above.
> - Please pay the pending salary of the ex-employees that I have mentioned.
> - Please pay the pending salary of the ex-employees listed above (or below).
> - Please pay the pending salary of the ex-employees that I mentioned to Mr Jones last week.
> - Please pay the pending salary of these ex-employees.

Other forms are possible, but please avoid "mentioned employees" or anything similar,

Comment: I used to work with people who spoke Indian English on a regular basis. My intuition is that the original sentence is acceptable in that dialect, but perhaps(?) abbreviated. It certainly sounds more like Indian English than any other dialect I'm familiar with.

Answer (score -1):

You would use **"mentioned"** like this if you had already named the individuals that this sentence is currently talking about (in this case, the ex-employees) earlier in the text.

For example, if I was to write a blog post about a few different search engines, I could name them at the start of the blog post and then later on use "mentioned" to avoid renaming them again.  Here is a small example of what I mean.

> The main search engines are Google and Bing.
>
> The (previously) mentioned search engines are estimated to generate over $100 billion in revenue every year.

The word "previously" is normally used before mentioned, since you are "mentioning" something that you already discussed, but the sentence still works and sounds normal to native speakers.

Comment: It is active voice or passive voice sentence?

Comment: @kuldeepsingh It would be the passive voice as the sentence is emphasizing the action of paying the employees rather than the employees themselves.

Comment: It could also refer to ‘about to be mentioned’ individuals rather than only ‘previously mentioned’.  It is reminiscent of an old-fashioned and trite way of wording formal letters and should be avoided in favour of plain English in the active voice. A similar word is “aforementioned”. Use something like “above” or “referred to” if it isn’t in fact clear already from the context, making the words just superfluous padding.  For example, if a list of names follows the sentence, then use “...these ex-employees...”

Comment: It is not passive - it is active, "Pay" is active. "Be paid" would be passive.